# How to automate select certificate popup on chrome using selenium python

Tags: python

How can I accept popup for select certificate in chrome?
[image]

I tried using pyautogui library

```
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Also all the codes below.

```
alert=driver.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy() 
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),desired_capablities=capabilities)
```

And nothing worked for me.

Comment: If you post what you actually tried, instead of just brief descriptions, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Please specify what the problem is. Also provide a [mre] so that someone can help you fix the problem.